# How do I instruct Excel to sum products of cells automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

In other words, how do I instruct Excel to calculate the sum in A1, WITHOUT any need to
compute firstly (in a separate new column) c<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n</sub>*b<sub>n</sub>
and to instruct secondly Excel to sum all c<sub>n</sub> ?

[image]

Comment: So you want to sum products?  Wouldn't it be great if there was a built-in function to do that?  They could even call it SUMPRODUCT.  Check this out: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. I did not know of this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older Excel versions, you can use the *Matrix* version of `SUM()`, which would be (in this example) `=SUM(A3:A5*B3:B5)`; note that you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> (instead of simply <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) to make it a *Matrix* formula. You can see the formula is then shown with `{}` around it to mark it as such.

This approach works also in newer versions, but in addition, there is `SUMPRODUCT()`, which does the same thing.